# Maven fails to download maven-psteclipse-plugin:jar:1.0.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a eclipse rcp plugin for which am setting up Maven build

All the configuration is done after reading this article - https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Eclipse-and-Maven2/index.html

Now while i try to create a jar file for the plugin using the command 'mvn install -U', i get the below error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...                                                                                    
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-psteclipse-plugin/1.0.3/maven-psteclipse-plugin-1.0.3.pom                                                                               
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-psteclipse-plugin:jar:1.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-psteclipse-plugin/1.0.3/maven-psteclipse-plugin-1.0.3.jar                                                                               
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin is missing. @ line 64, column 12                                                                                                           
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-psteclipse-plugin:1.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-psteclipse-plugin:jar:1.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @
 @                                                                                                                 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]                                                             
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.my.plugin:1.0.0 (C:\temp_ws\com.my.plugin\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-psteclipse-plugin:1.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-psteclipse-plugin:jar:1.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]                                                                                                            
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]                                                                                                            
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:          
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

Can anyone let me know in which repository i can find the 'maven-psteclipse-plugin' artifact and help in resolving this issue

Comment: Your source is a hundred years old ... don't try to follow that.

Comment: @JFMeier, is there a way to mavenize eclipse plugins? Would be helpful if you can throw some light on this.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/